# Fluentui Grid not working in SPFx work bench and also as an installed app

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, react, layouts

i want to use the fluentui grid layout in the SPFx Webpart with React as Framework.

the problem is that the grid is not working. As soon as i use it, it shows only the items under each other.

how I can solve it?

Here is my code so far:

```
 <div className="ms-Grid" dir="ltr">
      <div className="ms-Grid-row">
          <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-sm4 ms-xl4">A</div>
          <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-sm8 ms-xl8">B</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

I don't where to start. I tried different things, but it's still like working. I added the following links to my my .scss file:

```
@import '~office-ui-fabric-react/dist/sass/References.scss';
@import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';
:global{
  @import 'node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.css';
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Somehow  `@import 'node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.css';` not working.

Try to directly use: `import 'office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.css';` it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following document to deploy your Fluentui Grid

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/get-started/web#fluent-ui-react

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved